GCP Gemini API - Send multimodal prompt requests using local video
Hope someone can help.
The sample code shows how to send multimodal prompt requests with locally stored images:
import vertexai

from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Part, Image

model_id: str = "gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409"
project_id: str = "YOUR_GCP_PROJECT"
region: str = "YOUR_GCP_REGION"

vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=region)

model: GenerativeModel = GenerativeModel(model_name=model_id)

response = model.generate_content([
    Part.from_image(Image.load_from_file('image.jpg')),
    "What is shown in this image?",])

print(response.text)


I need to do simlar taks, but with locally saved videos but i've been struggling with it.
Is there any alternative for Part.from_uri?
i found documentation in
from https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/reference/python/1.59.0/vertexai.vision_models.Video#methods
but i failed to incorparate this

import vertexai   from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel, Part   import pathlib   project_id: str = "YOUR_GCP_PROJECT"   region: str = "YOUR_GCP_REGION"   vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=region)   model = GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash-001")   location = "path_to_file.mp4"   video_bytes = pathlib.Path(location).read_bytes()   video_file = Part.from_data(video_bytes,mime_type="video/mp4")   response = model.generate_content([video_file, "What’s in this video?"])   print(response.text)

Sorry can't seem to format it correctly. The main changes are get the bytes then do Part.from_data
